# webRequest.getSecurityInfo() does not work

Tags: javascript, webrequest

I'm tringto see how this works -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/getSecurityInfo but no luck so far.
There is ready to use example here -> https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples named root-cert-stats but it doesn't do anything after I've added this extension to firefox, there are examples here -> https://docs.w3cub.com/web_extensions/api/webrequest/getsecurityinfo as well but they don't work either. That is I think they don't work because I can't see anythig on the console.

Ican't even see this "debug message" it's me so I don't know whether this handler function is called or not

```
"use strict";
/*
Just draw a border round the document.body.
*/
document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";
console.log("hi there");
  
async function logSubject(details) {
    console.log("it's me")
    try {
      let securityInfo = await browser.webRequest.getSecurityInfo(details.requestId, {});
      console.log(details.url);
      if (securityInfo.state === "secure" || securityInfo.state === "weak") {
        console.log(securityInfo.certificates[0].subject);
      }
    }
    catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
  
  browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(logSubject,
    {urls: ["https://*.mozilla.org/*"]},
    ["blocking"]
  );
```

Maybe there is something wrong with manifest file or something like that.

Comment: Make sure you are running this on a compatible webbrowser. Almost none of the browsers except for Firefox and Firefox For Android are compatible using this feature.

Comment: @node_modules I'm running it on firefox so this is not the issue, something else is. :)